# Angular 2 npm start issue

Tags: angular, npm, package.json

When I tries to run command **npm start** at that time gives error like this:

[image]

My **package.json** file is :-

```
{
"name": "angular-quickstart",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p --progress",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"nodemon server/main.js\" \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "@ngui/map": "^0.18.3",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.26.14",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "angular2-image-upload": "^0.6.3",
    "angular2-modal": "^3.0.1",
    "angular2-useful-swiper": "^4.0.5",
    "auth0-js": "^8.7.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.3",
    "debug-log": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "http-server": "^0.10.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "mysql": "^2.13.0",
    "ng": "0.0.0-rc6",
    "ng2-float-btn": "0.0.3",
    "ng2-page-scroll": "^4.0.0-beta.9",
    "ng2-parallax": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-flickity": "0.0.6",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
},
"repository": {}
}
```

My **tsconfig.json** file is:-

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "dist"
  }
}
```

Please tell me what I need to change and how can I deploy project on the server?

Comment: you need to define the parameters i guess you are running the aot build where it is expecting the typings for the functions , you need to provide types for the same

Comment: please tell me how can i define type for parameter ? @RahulSingh

Comment: if you see the error statement you will see value has implict type any make it to what every you are passing like from value: any to value : //your type string or number or user defined type

Comment: If my value is string then how can i do ? please Give me one example(syntax) for it @RahulSingh

Comment: value:string should do the trick you might have to specify like this for all functions where its reflecting error

Comment: @RahulSingh Thank You for this I run this Poject, But still i problem with Deploy. I have no dist Folder. and **ng build** command not work for me.
I already install angular-cli **npm install -g angular-cli** , but ng command not working, so how can I do ?

Comment: cli is not installed locally or globally you need to install it both locally and globally

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit to the last good version keyz.Mist, please do not roll back edits unless you have good reason to. If you wish to insist on your version, please ping me so I can involve a moderator. I have now downvoted, to discourage this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add:

```
"noImplicitAny": "false"
```

to `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json` and it should resolve this issue.

Comment: this is already **false**, but still it gives error like this.

Comment: @keyz.Mist Would you mind sharing the tsconfig file?

Comment: Pleasre check tsconfig File in Quetion. @Chrillewoodz

Answer (score 0):

In my case i did

```
In package.json file
When I "npm start" the application didn't run, then I changed it to
"start": "concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" ", in package.json
then the application ran without errors.
```

Hope it helps

Comment: No, this is not the Problem.